# Kubernetes service discovery inside chroot

Tags: docker, kubernetes, chroot

I'm building a chroot env in docker for a code sandbox. I need to resolve service names such as http://internal-service inside the chroot env. I've tried copying resolv over with `RUN cp /etc/resolv.conf /jail/etc/resolv.conf` but when I ssh into the container the resolv.conf is different inside chroot. I've tried copying /etc/hosts as well but hostnames still wont work. Regular networking works fine. Anyone know a fix?

EDIT: the trick is to copy /etc/resolv.conf at runtime, during build does not work

Comment: Isn't this a container in a container in a way? :)

Comment: Yep it is, don't see another way to prevent scripts from editing the filesystem though

Comment: See "ReadOnlyRootFilesystem" on https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#volumes-and-file-systems